# Clear scr does not work

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I haven't been able to use the "clear scr" command in a while, as I get the following error:

```
root@server:~# clear                                                     
The program 'clear' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:  
apt-get install ncurses-bin                                                     
bash: clear: command not found

root@server:~# apt-get install ncurses-bin                               
Reading package lists... Done                                                   
Building dependency tree                                                        
Reading state information... Done                                               
ncurses-bin is already the newest version.                                      
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I'm using Ubuntu Server 9.10.

I did some development with the ncurses library a while ago, so I've no doubt broken something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-installing ncurses-bin from the terminal

`sudo aptitude reinstall ncurses-bin`

or

use Synaptic from Gnome Interface

`Settings > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager`